# Unable to login through admin panel of Joomla 3.3 site

Tags: account-password

I am unable to login through admin panel of my Joomla 3.3 site. I do not know why this happens each time a new website is launched. To address this issue, I tried to change my password by login to PHPMyAdmin page (GoDaddy cPanel). As I could not recollect the password that I set for PHPMyAdmin, I reset password.

Now, the site is not live even frontend. Getting the message both on frontend and backend:

*Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.*

This happened with me earlier and I was told not to reset password for PHPMyAdmin. In that case, I somehow recollected the original password. If that's the reason, the way forward is perhaps taking backup of existing MySQL which is still with me on my cPanel and restoring the same fresh with a new username and password. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double-check your `configuration.php` file.

Make sure the following fields are correct:

```
public $host = 'localhost'; /* Usually localhost, but I think GoDaddy uses a different location */
public $user = 'DB_USERNAME'; /* Insert a user with access to the database */
public $password = 'DB_USER_PASSWORD'; /* Make sure this is the password matching the user above */
public $db = 'DB_NAME'; /* Make sure the user above has access to THIS database */
```

You can see your database details (and change database password) on GoDaddy by logging in to your Account Manager. Then click *Web Hosting*, click *MySQL Databases*.

Once you get rid of the **Error: Could not connect to MySQL.** message, make sure you secure your Joomla installation (and any other Joomla you might have on the account), and change all passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest resetting your password via PHPmyAdmin unless you know what you're doing. Joomla 3.x uses `bycrypt` to you need to make sure you use the correct hash.

Also, the error you're getting isn't anything to with invalid login details. It simply means that it can't connect to the database because one or more of the database credentials are invalid. Double check your database details, then open the **configuration.php** and change the database setting accordingly.

Comment: I am working on your advise. To clarify though, first of all the website was hacked. Despite using correct username and password, I was unable to login for which reason I was in the process of changing my password.

Comment: Ah I see. In which case make sure you use a more secure database password and user password. You might also want to enable the two factor authentication plugin once everything is sorted which will add another layer of security. I would also suggest installing a firewall extension to check for any unknown files that may expose your site in the future

Comment: The same problem I encountered for few minutes today (Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL) both on frontend and backend; i.e., unable to access login menu. After say one minute, the issue sorted without doing anything.