# Cannot login to previously working Joomla site front end and back end

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, login

Front end and also Admin does not log in, and it does not error. It just seems to refresh.  I'm using Joomla 3.x

- I have tried overwriting all of the core files via FTP
- plg_user_joomla is enabled (checked via PHPMyAdmin)
- I have changed my PHP version from 7.3 to 7.2 and 7.1
- Nothing is set for the cookie domain in configuration.php
- error reporting is set to maximum
- I have changed the password to check that is correct but it is not saying incorrect password
- If I put an incorrect password, it does not tell me that error message
- I have disabled Admin Tools
- I have disabled Litespeed Cache
- I have checked plg_authentication_joomla and it is enabled
- I have renamed .htaccess from htaccess.txt to .htaccess
- I have replaced the Admin Tools .htaccess with the default Joomla .htaccess
- I have enabled error reporting to "Maximum" via FTP AND I have checked that the value held and is correct
- I have enabled Joomla debug
- I have manually deleted the cache folders from /cache and administrator/cache
- I have checked the "cookie domain" is empty in configuration.php
- I have checked the "live site" value is empty in configuration.php
- I have checked the site is https for the entire site
- I have checked there is no conflict with www and non-www or any redirect loop
- I have repaired the table in PHPMyAdmin
- I have optimized (sic) the table in PHPMyAdmin
- The last thing I remember doing that could cause this was installing a plugin email as user name.  I have renamed this folder "--email-as-username"
- Checked for JavaScript errors in the console on the login page
- Changed logs and administrator/logs to 777 file permissions
- Set all folders to 755 file permissions (save for logs)
- Set files to 644 file permissions (except for config which is 755)

The login has been working the entire time.  It is due to be released and suddenly there is a  problem.

## Other references:

- [Can't log in with admin, no error messages](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22549/cant-log-in-with-admin-no-error-messages)
- https://www.itoctopus.com/login-to-joomla-administrator-not-working-and-no-error-is-displayed
- [Cannot log in to Joomla (front and back) after site move](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/cannot-log-in-to-joomla-front-and-back-after-site-move)
- [Unable to login through admin panel of Joomla 3.3 site](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/unable-to-login-through-admin-panel-of-joomla-3-3-site)
- [Cannot login to administrator when hosted](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/19528/cannot-login-to-administrator-when-hosted)
- [Admin does not log in or error](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28489/admin-does-not-log-in-or-error)
- [I can't access the control panel in joomla 3.4](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14184/i-cant-access-the-control-panel-in-joomla-3-4)
- https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=965082
- https://www.itoctopus.com/10-reasons-why-youre-not-able-to-login-to-your-joomla-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using 2 databases one for dev and one for live.  My checks were all on the wrong database and it was in fact the Joomla authentication plugin that was disabled!